# Python website login and scrape page (delayed?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that's behind a login page.
I know how to login using Python's `requests.session()`.
However, when I retrieve the webpage, it seems to be not fully loaded.
The html I receive is different from the html shown when I login through a browser.

My code is this:

```
session = requests.session()
login_data = {'email': 'myemailaddress', 'password': 'mypassword'}
session.post(url_login, login_data)
r = session.get(url_homepage)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I'm getting the impression that the site does some scripting or redirecting after the initial loading of `url_homepage`

I've already tried to put in a `time.sleep(10)` between the `post` and the `get`, but that doesn't do the trick.
I'm guessing I need to have `session.get()` to wait a number of seconds before it does the actual get, but `session.get()` doesn't allow that.

Does anybody know how to do this, or can give me suggestions on how to proceed please?
I'm using Python 3.6 but solutions for other versions are ok too.

Comment: `r = requests.get(url_login, follow_redirects=True)` does this yield any different results? You can check the redirects with `r.url,` Is this the same value as when visited through the browser?

Comment: Sometimes the html content is different depending on 'User-Agent', try adding that to `headers` . Also, have you checked your cookies, ie : `session.cookies.get_dict()` ?

Comment: @0x52-0x75-0x63-0x79 `follow_redirects` doesn't seem to be a valid parameter. I get this error: `  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'follow_redirects'`

Comment: `allow_redirects=True` my apologies

Comment: @t.m.adam session.cookies does contain a cookie.

Comment: It may also be an idea to complete the login through the browser with some sort of proxy, Tamper Data is what i would use. You can correlate this data against the PreparedRequest you would have sent i.e: `print(r.request.body)` you can also check the sent headers with the `.headers` field

Comment: @0x52-0x75-0x63-0x79 allow_redirects works, but I get the same resulting html.

Comment: If it contains the same type of cookies you get when using a browser, that means you are authenticated. Also you can set `allow_redirects` to `False` and check  if `post.status_code` is 302

Comment: OK, check my previous comment then: will allow you to compare the data sent through either method, i bet you they wont mach in some way. @t.m.adam maybe correct with his cookie idea, that can also be set through requests very easily.

Answer (score 0):

For example (Linkedin).
You have to download [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (or other drivers), look at selenium [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
   username = 'my_login'
   password = 'my_pass'
   linkedin = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'

   #sign in
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   browser.get(linkedin)
   browser.find_element_by_name("session_key").send_keys(username)
   browser.find_element_by_name("session_password").send_keys(password)
   browser.find_element_by_name("signin").click()
   time.sleep(3)

   #scrape
   html = browser.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
   print(soup)

   #log out
   browser.find_element_by_id("nav-settings__dropdown-trigger").click()
   browser.find_element_by_link_text("Sign out").click()
   browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```